# how to pass a value from one table to a new column of another table in sql?

Tags: mysql

I created a table called users which stores the users' details. The user table has the fields call user_id(primary key), name, email, password, timestamps. After that, I created another table called 'test'. The test table columns are id(primary key auto increment),uid(user id),name,description(some random string).

I wanted to take and pass the values of user_id and name into the uid and name columns of test table respectively. For that, I created a trigger function.By using the trigger function, I wanted to pass the values to the uid and name fields in 'test' table.  but I got the error as below.

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/sameera/anaconda3/envs/customerbot/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
  return self.func(*args)
  File "gui_bot.py", line 152, in send
   cursor.execute(insertion)
   File "/home/sameera/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 163, in execute
  result = self._query(query)
  File "/home/sameera/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 321, in _query
  conn.query(q)
  File "/home/sameera/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 505, in query
  self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "/home/sameera/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 724, in _read_query_result
  result.read()
  File "/home/sameera/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1069, in read
  first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
   File "/home/sameera/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 676, in _read_packet
   packet.raise_for_error()
   File "/home/sameera/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 223, in raise_for_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
    File "/home/sameera/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 107, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
    pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'test.uid' in 'where clause'")
```

The user table structure

```
     CREATE TABLE users(
        user_id int(20) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
        name varchar(255),
        email varchar(255),
        password varchar(255),
    )
```

The test table structure

```
   CREATE TABLE test(
        id int(20) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
        uid int(20),
        name varchar(255),
        description varchar(255)
    )
```

The trigger function

```
"CREATE TRIGGER after_user_insert 
 AFTER INSERT 
        ON users FOR EACH ROW 
  BEGIN 
  INSERT INTO test(uid,name) 
      VALUES(NEW.user_id, NEW.name); 
   END;"
```

Insertion function

```
"""INSERT INTO test(uid,name)
    Select name,user_id 
    From users
    Where users.user_id = test.uid
 """
```

Can anyone explain the issue of the implementation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your trigger is on users but the insert is on test - trigger won’t fire

Comment: so does it mean that I need to switch the tables?